# Get all possible combinations from dictionary and list

Tags: python

I'm building a web scraper and want to generate all urls I want to request.
The URL has three parameters:

- date
- facility_id
- sport_id

I need to generate all possible combinations from a list of dates and a dictionary of facility and sport.

```
    dates = ['2020-10-21', '2020-10-22']
    db = {'facility_id': [184, 4, 3, 3], 'sport_id': [1, 2, 1, 5]}
```

The resulting URL looks like this (this would be the first result of eight (2 dates * 4 rows in dictionary)

```
    https://www.website.se/subsite?date=2020-10-21&facility_id=184&sport_id=1
```

I've tried a nested for loop but find myself stuck.

```
    url = 'https://www.website.se/subsite?'
    dates = ['2020-10-21', '2020-10-22']
    db = {'facility_id': [184, 4, 3, 3], 'sport_id': [1, 2, 1, 5]}
    
    for date in dates:
        url = url + date + ','
        
        for col in db:
            url = url + col + ','
            
            for values in db[col]:
                url = url + str(values) + ','
        print(url)
```

Is a nested for loop the way to go or is there a better way?

### The complete result I'm trying to generate

```
https://www.website.se/subsite?date=2020-10-21&facility_id=184&sport_id=1
https://www.website.se/subsite?date=2020-10-21&facility_id=4&sport_id=2
https://www.website.se/subsite?date=2020-10-21&facility_id=3&sport_id=1
https://www.website.se/subsite?date=2020-10-21&facility_id=3&sport_id=5
https://www.website.se/subsite?date=2020-10-22&facility_id=184&sport_id=1
https://www.website.se/subsite?date=2020-10-22&facility_id=4&sport_id=2
https://www.website.se/subsite?date=2020-10-22&facility_id=3&sport_id=1
https://www.website.se/subsite?date=2020-10-22&facility_id=3&sport_id=5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for date in dates:
    for fac_id, sport_id in zip(db['facility_id'], db['sport_id']):
        res = f'https://www.website.se/subsite?date={date}&facility_id={fac_id}&sport_id={sport_id}'
        print(res)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product


dates = ['2020-10-21', '2020-10-22']
db = {'facility_id': [184, 4, 3, 3], 'sport_id': [1, 2, 1, 5]}

for d, (f, s) in product(dates, zip(db['facility_id'], db['sport_id'])):
    print('https://www.website.se/subsite?date={}&facility_id={}&sport_id={}'.format(d, f, s))
```

Prints:

```
https://www.website.se/subsite?date=2020-10-21&facility_id=184&sport_id=1
https://www.website.se/subsite?date=2020-10-21&facility_id=4&sport_id=2
https://www.website.se/subsite?date=2020-10-21&facility_id=3&sport_id=1
https://www.website.se/subsite?date=2020-10-21&facility_id=3&sport_id=5
https://www.website.se/subsite?date=2020-10-22&facility_id=184&sport_id=1
https://www.website.se/subsite?date=2020-10-22&facility_id=4&sport_id=2
https://www.website.se/subsite?date=2020-10-22&facility_id=3&sport_id=1
https://www.website.se/subsite?date=2020-10-22&facility_id=3&sport_id=5
```

Comment: Was about to submit exactly this, but I'd use an f-string instead of `.format()`: `f"https://www.website.se/subsite?date={d}&facility_id={f}sport_id={s}"`  You can also shorten it a bit by doing `zip(*db.values())`.

Answer (score 0):

With your present code you are inserting `,` in the url. Here's a solution:

```
dates = ['2020-10-21', '2020-10-22']
db = {'facility_id': [184, 4, 3, 3], 'sport_id': [1, 2, 1, 5]}

for date in dates:  
  for col in db:  
    for values in db[col]:
      url = f"https://www.website.se/subsite?date={date}&facility_id={col}&sport_id={values}"
      print(url)
```

Not Sure there's a way around the nested loops.